# EmbeddedKafkaCluster missing?

Tags: apache-kafka, integration-testing, apache-kafka-streams

This blog entry https://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-processing-part-2-testing-your-streaming-application/ refers to the class EmbeddedKafkaCluster, which is supposed to be in the library kafka-streams-test-utils.

However, this class is missing in the library, e.g. org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams-test-utils/2.5.1.

I thought that I can use the source code from github https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/utils/EmbeddedKafkaCluster.java

But this source code refers to some classes, e.g. kafka.zk.EmbeddedZookeeper and kafka.utils.MockTime, that I assumed must be in the library like org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.13/2.5.1. Unfortunately, they are also missing.

What is the best way to configure a project to use the EmbeddedKafkaCluster in this case?

Thanks

Boris

Comment: That repo isnt the actual Kafka source code. Also, are you using Maven? If so, there are classifiers that add test classes

Comment: Indeed, I tried the test classifiers - but it did not help

Comment: I know there was a JIRA about making the embedded servers easier to integrate. The spring-kafka one is widely used otherwise. Or, are you able to use docker? https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/

Comment: Part of our development takes place on Windows where docker is not installed (cannot be installed). As of now, we will look into github.com/salesforce/kafka-junit . We will also use some of the source code available for EmbeddedSingleNodeCluster to integrate the schema registry.

Comment: There's this https://medium.com/bakdata/transparent-schema-registry-for-kafka-streams-6b43a3e7a15c Though, I wonder if mock objects will work fine for you rather than actually starting servers

Comment: thanks a lot! this might be useful in setting up the schema registry!

Answer (score 3):

Add the following dependencies:

```
    //build.gradle

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-junit', version: '2.0.0.0'

    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.13', version: '2.7.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.13', version: '2.7.0', classifier:'test'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-streams', version: '2.7.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-streams', version: '2.7.0', classifier: 'test'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-streams-test-utils', version:  '2.7.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.7.0', classifier: 'test'
```

If you’re using Maven, convert all dependencies based on this code:

```
//pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
</dependency>
```

And create the EmbeddedKafkaCluster in the following way (Kotlin example):

```
    @Test
    fun createEmbeddedKafkaClusterTest() {

        val NUM_BROKERS = 1
        val embeddedKafkaCluster = EmbeddedKafkaCluster(NUM_BROKERS)
        Assert.assertNotNull(embeddedKafkaCluster)

        embeddedKafkaCluster.start()

        embeddedKafkaCluster.createTopic("TestTopic")
    }
```